# DB2 command change to Postgres command

Tags: postgresql

DB2 command to Postgres command.

```
 db2 IMPORT FROM test.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY USEDEFAULTS COMMITCOUNT 100000 "INSERT_UPDATE INTO TEST.person (name,old,sex)" > ${TEMPTXT}
```

How can i use postgres command to do the same thing like this db2 command to import from file to insert and update the table ?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has `COPY`, but it doesn't perform update.So, first run `COPY` into a `TEMP` table and then merge into main table.

For a comma delimiter,

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE TEST.tmp_person (name text,old text,sex text)
COPY  TEST.tmp_person FROM test.csv WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV
--         ^temp table
```

There are various techniques in Postgres to do `INSERT_UPDATE` or merge. Refer [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql) post. Use proper casting to appropriate target data types while inserting/updating.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any better way to get the data from csv file to insert and update the table?